# How to disable Swagger UI syntax highlighting in Springdoc?

Tags: swagger-ui, springdoc

I'm using `springdoc-swagger-ui`. It is a known issue that Swagger UI is unable to handle large responses, and the suggested workaround is to disable syntax highlighting in Swagger UI.

I tried to add the following configuration in `application.yaml` for my Spring Boot application but it has no effect. I still see response is highlighted.

```
springdoc:
  swagger-ui:
    syntax-highlight:
      activated: false
```

Any leads on how to disable syntax highlighting in Swagger UI using Springdoc configs or `application.properties`?

Comment: 1) What version of Springdoc do you use? 2) What is your Swagger UI version? Open the browser dev tools -> Console tab and evaluate `versions`.

Comment: When do you say large response, what's the approximate size of the response? It's not a good idea to render a large amount of data using Swagger-UI.

Comment: Works with version - SpringBoot v2.6.6 & org.springdoc:springdoc-openapi-ui-v1.6.12

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `SpringBoot v2.7.4` and `org.springdoc:springdoc-openapi-ui-v1.6.8`, I was able to change it by modifying the

`src/main/resources/application.properties`

```
springdoc.swagger-ui.syntax-highlight.activated=false
```

Comment: Thank you @sxsnyc. It wasn't working before but finally it is working with springdoc-openapi-ui v1.6.12 & springboot 2.6.6

Answer (score 0):

The settings in application.yaml are correct.

I think it's probably because I'm using cache for js files.

For example, you can check what is not cached by accessing with the following URL.
`(domain)/swagger-ui/swagger-initializer.js?a=a`

```js
   window.ui = SwaggerUIBundle({
...
     deepLinking: true,
     syntaxHighlight: {activated: false},
presets: [
...
```

Try doing a hard refresh in your browser.