# Swagger SpringDoc: Expanding endpoint freezes browser tab

Tags: spring, swagger, swagger-ui

I have a single-endpoint Spring service that takes a large/complex XML input, and
returns a similarly formatted output. It is defined like so:

```java
@Operation(summary = "Sample Request", operationId = " sampleReq", description = " Data Structure Response", responses = {
        @ApiResponse(responseCode = "200", description = "Data Structure response with calculations ") })
@PostMapping(consumes = { MediaType.APPLICATION_XML_VALUE }, produces = { MediaType.APPLICATION_XML_VALUE })
public ResponseEntity<ComplexStructure> calculate(@RequestBody ComplexStructure request) {
    // ...
}
```

When I have it set up like this, loading the webpage causes it to hang after expanding the POST operation.

[image: Broken POST Request]

What I'd like to do is simply remove the (what I assume is breaking it) schema generation. For example, I'm fine if it looks like this: To achieve this example, I replaced `ComplexStructure` with `String`, but I'd rather not do that.

[image: Schema-less POST Request]

Comment: Try disabling syntax highlighting in Swagger UI, sometimes it helps avoid problems with large responses. If you use Springdoc, [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75218362/113116). If you use standalone Swagger UI dist assets, add [`syntaxHighlight: false`](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui/blob/master/docs/usage/configuration.md#user-content-syntaxhighlight) to its configs.

Comment: @Helen I was able to verify the configuration worked with my sample configuration (the red and grey text both turned white), but it had no impact on the UI freezing in the real code. I also note that the browser memory usage seems to spike (no matter which browser I use), getting into the 10+GB of memory used.